# how to explain this C language code from ffmpeg remuxing

Tags: c, ffmpeg

can someone help me what the meaning of this code? this is a code from ffmpeg remuxing code.

```
static void log_packet(const AVFormatContext *fmt_ctx, const AVPacket *pkt, const char *tag, int hours, int mins, int secs, int us, int *time )
{
    AVRational *time_base = &fmt_ctx->streams[pkt->stream_index]->time_base;
    total = total + pkt->duration;
  //  printf( "%d:%d:%d.%d \n", hours,  mins,  secs, us );
    *time = av_q2d(*time_base) * pkt->pts ;
}
```

I'm kind of new to C language. thank you!

Comment: Why did you tag this with "java" ?

Comment: what part exactly don't you understand?

Comment: @erwin ups i'm sorry my bad, i'll delete it :D

Comment: @morcillo all of that function, i can't understand what the meaning of -> *

Comment: @Fidona I've already deleted it, I was just wondering if I was missing something

Comment: @Fidona: You should read about "Pointers in C".

Comment: @Fidona .. I aggree with Mayurk. Do you know what a struct is and what a pointer is? I'm assuming you do. When you declare a struct and want to access its members you do something like this ... "mystruct.member1 = 1; mystruct.member2 = 1" and so on. When you have a pointer and you want to access its value you do something like this "*myPtr = 5". When you have a pointer to s truct and want to access one of its members you do it with "->" instead o "."

Comment: @Fidona this line "AVRational *time_base = &fmt_ctx->streams[pkt->stream_index]->time_base;" ... you are creating a pointer to an AVRational variable called time_base ... and you are pointing  it to a member of a struct that contains a member called streams which is either a pointer or a buffer and you access its index given another structure ... and this member called stream has another member called time_base, which you are assigning to your time_base, so it's safe to assume they are the same type

Comment: @Fidona I must add that this is not a good explanation. You really should read about struct and pointers. You could also access the members of a structure like this (*myPtrToStruct).member1 = 9;